# Spring Security + JWT: How to enrich Authentication/Principal after successful login?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I’ve got a question which seems popular, but I couldn’t find the answer. Well there’s a lot of information about it but I’m not sure what the best way is. So here’s the scenario.

We have a Single Page Application (SPA) and a RESTful Web Service (API). We use an external authentication/authorization service provider via OAuth2/JWT. But I need to persist the user ID (provided by the external authentication provider) on the database on the server side after successful login. And also I need to enrich the `Authentication`/`Principal` object in security context after successful login (for example by adding email).

There's a lot on the web about this scenario. But we have SDK for authentication/authorization already and it works perfectly (no custom code, etc). I just need to add something to the authentication object. What is the correct way to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the record, this is what we did:
As I said there's already a SDK doing all the heavy lifting of authentication mechanics. We just need to enrich the authentication object after successful authentication. So we wrapped the `AuthenticationProvider` (implemented in the SDK) in our implementation (inspired by `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider`) and after successful authentication, we enriched the result using our UserDetails implementation (inspired by `PreAuthenticatedGrantedAuthoritiesUserDetailsService`). The rest was straight forward.

PS: please let me know if you don't like the idea.

Comment: I was looking for the same, and found your answer inspiring. I took the same approach for a http.jee() configuration.

Comment: hey thanks for the explanation, any chance you could post the code somewhere? I have been strugling with the exact same use-case

Comment: Hi thanks for the info. I am struggling with the same issue. Could you maybe share the code? will be very helpfull!